# Azure Logic Apps- Can I used initialized variables in my dynamic content as the credentials for my SFTP server connection?

Tags: sftp, azure-logic-apps, dynamic-content

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server to pull a file in my Logic App. The credentials to connect to the server are secrets in an Azure KeyVault and I successfully accessed the credentials and saved them as individual variables within my logic app. I sequentially selected the "SFTP- SSH" action and when I try to enter the credentials the option to enter either "Dynamic Content" or "Expression" does not showing up essentially forcing me to hard code the credential values in which is something I do not want to do for security/use case reasons. Is there anyway around this where I can actually enter the Dynamic Content variables as values for my SFTP server credentials?